# What lens should a traveller buy?

Tags: lens, nikon, telephoto

I am a traveller. I like taking walking tours and clicking pictures of people in the street.

Once i developed a passion for photography, New York was the first place in visited. I used a 35 mm Nikon lens to shoot pictures. This lens was perfectly apt for NYC, considering the street width as well as for night photography.

Though this lens is not great for tele-photos, I used to shoot pictures and crop in. But now i feel this camera is restricting my experiments.

[image]

[image]

Both these pictures were cropped and hence sharpness is lost in this process.

Please suggest me help picking up my next lens.
I have a 18-55mm and a 35 mm lens currently. Once i buy a new one, i dont want to carry my 18-55 lens.

Comment: "But now i feel this camera is restricting my experiments." Restricting how?

Comment: One thing I do not understand. You are asking about fixed focus distances. You are using a 35 mm fixed length lens. You do not want to use your zoom kit lens, and you accept as an answer another zoom lens...

Comment: @Rafael i wasnt asking about fixed focus distances. I want to use a better lens than my zoom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a Tamron 16-300mm (APS-C lens) for travel, the flexibility is really good. The lens is obviously a compromise, and it's a very slow lens.

But as a one lens for all purposes for travel, I can't think of anything better (or I haven't tried any lens that fits me better).

You can see some video reviews here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9LudX0GmLZQ

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NPOHYxhVBm4

Answer (score 2):

Do some math:

If you took a picture on your 35 mm and you cropped, lets say the width:

- 50% you need a 70mm lens.
- 75% (leaving just 1/4 of the total width) 140mm (150) lens.

And so on.

But if you are not cropping in exact proportions all your photos you need a zoom lens, for example a 70-200mm or 55-200mm.

Look for a good quality one or you will leave it at home with your kit lens.

But, I personally would carry my kit zoom lens for travel until I find a suitable replacement... (another 18-55 mm zoom lens, just better quality)